# how to add buttons in notification in android using parse

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Can we add the action buttons while sending the push notification using parse  in  android ?

I made a push notification app in android using parse api. But I am only able to show a launch icon, a message and a title. I want some Action Buttons in the notification.

I know how to do it using android notification but don't know how to make that happen with parse.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the solution. We can add customise buttons with some action in notification using parse.

For this we have to use CustomBroadcastReceiver which extends the ParsePushBroadcastReceiver. And in that we can override the getNotification() function.

Create our Notification as we want using NotificationCompat.builder and return that notification.

For adding the buttons we can use .addAction function on the Notification builder.

Example code: its not the complete code.

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.someicon)
                            .setContentText(" something Up!!!")
                            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(
                                    "someLargeText"))
                            .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_call, "Call", contentIntentCall)
                            .addAction(R.drawable.closenew, "out of stock", contentIntentOutOfStock)
                            .setAutoCancel(true);
```

Two intent contentIntentCall and contentIntent is called while clicking on the button.

For finally build the notification use

mBuilder.build();